# Is using var foo = new RegExp necessary?

Tags: javascript, regex

While researching the use of regular expressions in javascript, one can encounter examples of two types:

A:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

B:

```
var regex = new RegExp ("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

**Is it necessary to use `var foo = new RegExp`? Or, when should one pick each method?**

Comment: @JamesMontagne I guess my question is much more basic..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `RegExp()` constructor is useful when you have to assemble a regular expression dynamically at run time.  If the expression is completely static, it's easier to use the native regex syntax (your "A"). The ease-of-use of the native syntax stems from the fact that you don't have to worry about quoting backslashes, as you do when your regular expression begins life as a string constant.

Comment: In addition, an important difference is when the expression is compiled (at evaluation vs. run-time) which may be expensive when dealing with large datasets and/or many regular expressions.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp that's a good point; I don't know how much of a difference it makes in modern JavaScript engines. I think there used to be an explicit ".compile()" function, but that's been deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to use `var foo = new RegExp`?

No, obviously not. The other one works as well.

> Or, when should one pick each method?

[Regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are easier to read and write as you do not need to string-escape regex escape characters - you can just use them (backslashes, quotes). Also, they are parsed only once during script "compilation" - nothing needs to be executed each time you the line is evaluated.

The [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) only needs to be used if you want to build regexes dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a 'dynamic' regular expression where you might need `new RegExp`.

```
var search = 'dog',
    re = new RegExp('.*' + search + '.*');
```

If it's a static regular expression, then the literal syntax (your A option) is better because it's easier to write and read.